# How to substitute dependency for a specific variant of Kotlin MPP dependency via attribute selectors?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

This question has nothing to do with Kotlin multiplatform (Kotlin MPP) in that sense that from gradle point of view, Kotlin MPP configuration is just a particular case of multivariant build.
So, imagine I want to redefine particular variant of dependency, for instance, I want to have a javascript module redefined. This approach works perfectly well:

```kotlin
substitute(module("org.shabunc.demo:lib-js")).using(project(":lib-js"))
```

However it works because I know that for a common dependency "org.shabunc.demo" the "org.shabunc.demo-js" corresponds to the js variant of dependency.

I've decided to experiment with more advanced approach where I'm redefining the variant dependency, and I've tried to do something like this:

```kotlin
       val kotlinPlatformTypeAttr = Attribute.of("org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type", KotlinPlatformType::class.java)
       ...
       substitute(variant(module("org.shabunc.demo:lib")) {
                attributes {
                    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage::class.java, "kotlin-api"))
                    attribute(kotlinPlatformTypeAttr, KotlinPlatformType.js)
                }   
            }).using(variant(project(":lib-js")) {
                attributes {
                    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage::class.java, "kotlin-api"))
                    attribute(kotlinPlatformTypeAttr, KotlinPlatformType.js)
                }   
            })
```

However this not working as expected, the compileKotlinMetadata is not resolving any entity defined in a common part of `org.shabunc.demo:lib`

My question is pretty straightforward: How can I redefine specific variant of Kotlin MPP dependency without relying on its name rather than on the name of common dependency?

Comment: Hello, @shabunc! Could you please tell if the problem is still relevant? I've also found a similar issue at Kotlin's issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47441. If it does not represent your exact case, maybe you would like to make an issue describing it at the https://kotl.in/issue?